# Redundant Firewalls And Switches HSRP and CARP

Tags: firewall, pfsense, redundancy, hsrp, carp

I currently have planned

```
2 x uplinks (HSRP Active/Standby)
2 x pfsense firewalls (Carp Enabled)
2 x layer2 switches
```

Please criticize or offer help on the correct way to do this.
I have a feeling im missing a valid point of simple networking.

The firewalls bridge the links EXT to INT, and the INT links are using LAGG for redundancy

[image]

Comment: Are your uplinks routing subnets to a single IP (CARP)? Are you trunking any VLANs to the L2 switches (do you need VLAN redundancy)? Your diagram looks like you'll be relying on STP, which would be a potential issue (STP loops happen just when you don't want them to!).

Comment: The Uplinks are routing an entire public block /25 and they are using HSRP.
THe firewalls however communicate independantly on a seperate line using CARP.
Is STP really that bad?? Any suggestions on a better alternative????

Comment: Do you not have a glue block for the sole purpose of routing your /25 - or are you planning on subnetting that yourself? Also, what is the intention for this, is it for a LAN/re-selling hosting etc.

Comment: noo.. im using the whole block :)
its a gateway to a very large cluster of servers in our datacenter.

Comment: Are you planning on 1:1 NAT'ing all the IPs then? Otherwise, your firewalls won't be doing much? I would have thought a `/29` glue block for routing, then route your `/25` to that glue block, then present your `/25` in a LAN/VLAN behind the FWs

Comment: The firewalls are doing alot..
it filters all the traffic, packet inspection, intrusion detection, amongst other stuff.
they are transparent..

Please explain your glue block and its benefits.